# How to bake an animated bezier curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have created a vine like structure from a Bezier curve and used another bezier curve as its taper object. I have then animated the bevel to make it appear to grow.
I'm trying to import this animation in to SPARK AR and other videos seem to suggest BAKING it. But I've tried with no success.

Is there an alternative way to make this animation i.e. with an object and modifier or is there an additional step when baking Bezier curves?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to mesh animation, game engines commonly support only two things: bone deformations and shape keys. Anything else "might" be supported, in some corner cases, but most of the time it's pointless to go out of the known road.

I don't know SPARK AR but considering how you made your animation, I'd suggest you to try to export your mesh as an alembic file, most modern game engines support alembic or at least interpret it as a mesh with a bunch of shapekeys.

If this doesn't work, then I guess you will have to redo your asset with your target software's limitations in mind. Which you should ALWAYS do in any project.